# CKeditor + Media: insert image tag rather than link to image

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, media

I want to insert an image into node body content using Ckeditor and Media. Everything seems to work except all I get is a link to the image file but I would like it to insert an image tag. When I click Ckeditor's **Add Media** button and choose an image I get an option **Current format is** and I can choose from **Default, Preview** and **Teaser**. While the first two return nothing, Teaser at least inserts a link to the image file.

How can I get it to insert an image tag instead of a link?

I am using Drupal 7.22 with Media 7.x-2.0-unstable7, Wysiwyg 7.x-2.2 and the latest Ckeditor.

Comment: I know it is possible. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069162/drupal-media-wysiwyg-ckeditor-inserting-image-issues). What needs to be configured to achieve this?

Comment: Found a solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

[Insert](https://drupal.org/project/insert) Module will do that, it will place the image in body field. Support for all major WYSIWYG editors, including tinyMCE, CKeditor.

> Insert is a utility that makes inserting images and links to files
>   into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple
>   JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets. When used
>   with ImageField and ImageCache, images may be inserted into text areas
>   with a specific ImageCache preset.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess it would work but I would loose the library features of Media, right? Let's say, I would like to use the same image in another node. Does Insert allow me to reuse the same image or does it have to uploaded again?

Comment: You need to upload again

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trying and searching for answers I finally found an answer. It turns out that **Media 7.x-2.0-unstable7 and Wysiwyg 7.x-2.2 currently only support CKeditor up to version 4.0.3**. Any version greater than that will, at least for now, fail. If you have to downgrade your CKeditor version and have mixed up buttons make sure to empty your cache. After that the Media button works as expected and lets you insert images using image styles defined at `admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/file-display`. Hope this helps anybody!